# React Navigation does not being accessed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

I am trying to create an intro swiper and when I get to change the screen from `WelcomeScreen` to `LoginScreen` I receive `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')`.

Here is my StackNavigator from App.js

```
export const SignedOut = StackNavigator({
  WelcomeScreen: {
    screen: Welcome
  },
  SwiperScreen: {
    screen: Swiper
  },
  LoginScreen: {
    screen: Login
  }
});
```

Here is the code from Welcome.js where you can see there is an TouchableOpacity with onPress method which works properly

```
import Swiper from "./Swiper";

export default class Welcome extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null };
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <Swiper>
        <View style={styles.slide}>
          <FontAwesome name="airplane" {...iconStyles} />
          <Text style={styles.header}>title one here</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, tellus at consectetur facilisis, quam nibh convallis diam, ullamcorper egestas dolor massa a augue.</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.slide}>
          <FontAwesome name="airballoon" {...iconStyles} />
          <Text style={styles.header}>title two here</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, tellus at consectetur facilisis, quam nibh convallis diam, ullamcorper egestas dolor massa a augue.</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.slide}>
          <FontAwesome name="amazon" {...iconStyles} />
          <Text style={styles.header}>title three here</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, tellus at consectetur facilisis, quam nibh convallis diam, ullamcorper egestas dolor massa a augue.</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}>
              <Text>START NOW</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the render of button from Swiper.js

```
renderButton = () => {
    const lastScreen = this.state.index === this.state.total - 1;
    return (
      <View
        pointerEvents="box-none"
        style={[styles.buttonWrapper, styles.fullScreen]}
      >
        {lastScreen ? (
          <Button
            text="Start Now"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}
          />
        ) : (
          <Button text="Continue" onPress={() => this.swipe()} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the navigation prop to `Swiper`:

```
<Swiper navigation={navigation}>
```

Alternatively:

```
<Swiper onStart={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}>
```

Then in `Swiper` just call

```
onPress={this.props.onStart}
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks